# Why are all predictions made by XGBoost distinct?

Tags: cart, boosting

If I understood correctly the XGBoost is a framework that operates on gradient tree boosting. It means that behind the scenes, it uses a decision tree to make a prediction. So, from what I read in the *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by G.James et al., I should obtain a finite number of predicted values. This deduction comes from a particular fragment (chapter 8, p. 306), namely:

> 1. We divide the predictor space—that is, the set of possible
>      values for X1,...,Xp into J distinct and non-overlapping
>      regions, R1,...,RJ.
> 2. For every observation that falls into the region Rj, **we make the
>      same prediction**, which is simply the mean of the response
>      values for the training observations in Rj.
>
> Suppose that in Step 1, we obtain two regions and that the
>   response mean of the training observations in the first region is 10,
>   while the response mean in the second region is 20. Then for a
>   given observation X = x, if x ∈ R1, we will predict a value of 10,
>   and if x ∈ R2, we will predict a value of 20.

After having trained the model with maximum depth of 10 (that would give 1024 distinct nodes), I made predictions on a test set and I found out that I have 524000 distinct values which means that I have a unique value for each row in the dataset.

In the light of the quoted fragment, my question is - why is it so? Why are all my predicted values distinct?

Here's my python code, if it's needed:

```
XGB_PARAMETERS = {
    'eta': 0.2, 
    'nthread': 4, 
    'min_child_weight': 30, 
    'max_depth': 10,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.7, 
    'subsample': 0.8,        
    'eval_metric': 'rmse',
    'silent':1
 }

model = xgb.train(
    XGB_PARAMETERS,
    d_test,
    150,
    watchlist,
    early_stopping_rounds=10,
    maximize=False,
    verbose_eval=10)

d_final_test = xgb.DMatrix(test[f2].values)
ypred = model.predict(d_test)
y_test = model.predict(d_final_test)
test['duration'] = np.exp(y_test) - 1
```

Comment: You mean, how I checked that all values are distinct? I just executed print(len(test['duration'].unique()))

Comment: Your trees may have a maximum depth of 10, but you have 150 of them, and the final prediction is a weighted sum of each of the 150 individual trees' predictions... that gives a *lot* of possible values as the output, even allowing for correlation between trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is defining a GBM of 150 trees with maximum depth 10. The predicted values are therefore not based on a single (rather deep) tree but actually on the ensemble of 150 trees. Given that each tree can potentially estimate $1024$ different values theoretically we can have up to $1024^{150}$ distinct values which is a relatively affluent number. I would suggest using a very small number of leaves as well as trees and then slowly increase the number of trees; that way the recursive partitioning of the sample space (through piece-wise flat functions) is will be easier to visualise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you are using `subsample`, which means that you are enabling stochastic gradient descent. See the [parameters documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html).